# Codename One SQL database storing wrong values

Tags: java, mysql, database, codenameone

I am used to developing desktop applications with Java. Now I am trying Codename One to develop my first mobile app.

Trying to replicate my experiences with SQL databases I am running into a very odd storage behavior, which I cannot explain.

The database is created, but when I change the table input value, the new value gets ignored and just the old value is added. To save the new value, I have to delete the database.

I like the interface and any kind help would be appreciated.

```
Database db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("MyDB.db");

db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Persons (Date NOT NULL,Event NOT NULL)");




String sql = "INSERT INTO Persons (DATE , Event) " + "VALUES ( 'John', '10000.00' );"; 
db.execute (sql);

// adds "John" to the database every time I click the button 
// then I change the from "John" to "James"
// I am not adding the lines twice, just change the input



String sql = "INSERT INTO Persons (DATE , Event) " + "VALUES ( 'James', '10000.00' );"; 
db.execute (sql);

//keeps adding "John" to the database, even though value has been changed to "James" 




Cursor cur = db.executeQuery("select * from Persons;");
Row currentRow= cur.getRow();
String dataText = currentRow.getString(0);

while (cur.next()) {
             System.out.println(dataText);
        }
```

Comment: You have to specify the datatype of the table columns when you create the table.

Comment: You're not updating `dataText` inside your `while()` loop.

Comment: Your column names don't seem to match the data you're putting into them. `John` doesn't look like a date, and why would an event be a number? The number looks more like a price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not fetching the next row into `dataText` in your `while()` loop, so you're just repeatedly printing out the text from the first row.

It should be:

```
Cursor cur = db.executeQuery("select * from Persons;");
while (cur.next()) {
    Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
    String dataText = currentRow.getString("Date");
    System.out.println(dataText);
}
```

If you examine the table with a separate query tool, like `PhpMyAdmin`, you should see that it contains both rows.

I hope I got the syntax right. I'm not a Java programmer and I got it from a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html).

Comment: Barmar, thanks but not working. In Codename One, there is no method  cur.getText ()... it exist in Java MySQL, as ResulSet rs.getText(), though ....

Comment: Make it a `ResultSet` instead of `Cursor`.

Comment: I tried something else, maybe it's right. But the main point is that you have to get the row inside the loop, not just once.

Comment: There is no result set but the concept is similar. In every loop of the while you need to do these two lines. `Row currentRow= cur.getRow();`
`String dataText = currentRow.getString(0);` You might also want to add `String secondColumn =  currentRow.getString(1);` since you have two columns in the table

Comment: Now I see, this isn't standard Java, it's part of CodeNameOne. I found the `Cursor` documentation [here](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/db/Cursor.html), and it has a big example showing the proper way to use it.

Comment: Shai Almog, Barmar, many thanks. The problem really was iterating through and not saving. Tried it out first thing this morning and worked like a charm.